# How to add seaborn library in jupyter lite static build

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, jupyter-irkernel, jupyter-console

I have created the static build of jupyter lite while running seaborn library example code in jupyter lite tool i am getting this error : seaborn module not found.

Comment: Please clarify your question, describing what you tried, what kernel you use (I guess assume pydide) and edit tags to only include relevant ones (jupyterhub, irkernel and console do not appear relevant).

Answer (score 0):

First of all import matplotlib library then import seaborn library like,
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn
(**plt** and **sn** is like rename or short name you can write anything like this place)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the beginning of your notebook

```
import piplite
await piplite.install('seaborn')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
```

[Sample notebook image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZJG2.png)